# MediatR request handler is not called from another location

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatr

When I call MediatR Send() from controller, handler get called.

```
    private readonly IMediator _requestsRouter;

    public async Task<DTO.UserAccount> GetUserAccount()
    {
        var req = new GetUserAccount(x, y, z, y);     
        var response = await _requestsRouter.Send(req);
        return response;
    }
```

Calling the same MediatR request from another MediatR request also works:

```
Controller -> MediatR_Request _1 -> GetUserAccount request handler
```

This also works except of last step:

```
Controller -> MediatR_Request_0 -> MediatR Notification -> MediatR Request _1(the same as before) -> does not arrive to GetUserAccount Handler.
```

I checked IMediator _requestsRouter from the step before (`MediatR Request#1`), it has GetUserAccount handler registered like this:

[image]

Suspicious messages in VS Debug console: "Exception thrown: *'System.ObjectDisposedException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll*
and  *'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll"*

It is not possible to debug, not arriving to handler. 
How can I troubleshoot the issue?

Are there any limitations for nesting MediatR requests, notifications?

Comment: It is difficult to identify your problem as you posted very little details. Are you sure you injected all the required dependencies?

Comment: @Ben I have only one dependency to send MediatR requests and notifications, it is  IMediator _requestsRouter (constructor injection). As you can see from screenshot it is created and has GetUserAccount registered.

Comment: @Ben Actually it indeed looks like DI container can not instantiate MediatR handler, it has no  problem with this when I send from controller or other request, How can I debug this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing **await** in the first MediatR  .Publish() call. As I understand no `await` caused ObjectDisposedException which is gone now.